# How to call a static method in mainActivity from a custom FirebaseListAdapter class?

Tags: android, firebase

I want to pop up an alert view in mainActivity from ChatListAdapter class using Firebase.

**Problem/Error:**

> com.firebase.androidchat.Main.activity.this cannot be reference from a static context

**Code in ChatListAdapter:**

```
public class ChatListAdapter extends FirebaseListAdapter<Chat> {

...

protected void populateView(View view, Chat chat) {
...    
    MainActivity.displayAmountPopup();
}
```

**Code in ChatListAdapter:**

```
public static void displayAmountPopup(){

....

    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle(strTitle)
            .setMessage(strAmountMessage)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                    // Present Acknowledgement View!!!!!!!!!
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AcknowledgementActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    /*Couldn't work this Error:local variable mContext is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AcknowledgementActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, AcknowledgementActivity.class));*/
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("AlertDialog", "Negative");
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> com.firebase.androidchat.Main.activity.this cannot be reference from a static context

Because not possible to access `MainActivity.this` from `static` method/block.

To get Context for showing `AlertDialog` add one Context parameter to  `displayAmountPopup` method:

```
public static void displayAmountPopup(Context mContext){
....
    new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
    ....
}
```

Now pass context to `displayAmountPopup` method when calling from `populateView` as:

```
MainActivity.displayAmountPopup(view.getContext());
```

Comment: Thx @ρяσѕρєя K, what if I have a startActivity inside my AlertDialog (commented out in my code above)

Comment: @user1872384: on `setPositiveButton` button click AlertDialog is auto dismissed before starting Activity. what you want  to do?

Comment: I want to present the acknowledgement view once the "ok" button is pressed

Comment: @user1872384: ok use `Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AcknowledgementActivity.class);mContext.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @user1872384: if `mContext ` is not accessible  inside `onClick` method then declare it as final in method parameter  like:`public static void displayAmountPopup(final Context mContext)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use context in the dialog
and cast activity to start Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AcknowledgementActivity.class);
((Activity) context).startActivity(intent)
```

from the commented code

```
public static void displayAmountPopup(Context context){

....

    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setTitle(strTitle)
            .setMessage(strAmountMessage)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                    // Present Acknowledgement View
                    //Intent intent = new Intent(context, AcknowledgementActivity.class);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Log.d("AlertDialog", "Negative");
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```